# Почему не отправляется некоторые поля с формы на Email?

Tags: php

Добрый день! 
Прошу помощи! Не отправляется номер телефона и адрес Email на почту. В письме пустое поле. Что может быть и как исправить? При чем имя отправляется на почту корректно.

```
/* Здесь проверяется существование переменных */
if (isset($_POST['phone'])) {$phone=$_POST['phone'];}

if (isset($_POST['name'])) {$name=$_POST['name'];}

if (isset($_POST['addres'])) {$addres=$_POST['addres'];}

/* Сюда впишите свою эл. почту */

 $address = "s@yandex.ru";

/* А здесь прописывается текст сообщения, \n - перенос строки */

$mes = "Тема: Заказ обратного звонка! \nТелефон: $phone\nИмя: $name\nE-mail: $addres";

/* А эта функция как раз занимается отправкой письма на указанный вами email */

$sub='Заказ'; //сабж
$email='Заказ <bigbur.ru>'; // от кого
 $send = mail ($address,$sub,$mes,"Content-type:text/plain; charset = utf-8\r\nFrom:$email");

ini_set('short_open_tag', 'On');
header('Refresh: 3; URL=index1.html');
```

Comment: что будет, если в POST-массиве не окажется элементов `addres` и `phone`?

Comment: и сам же отвечу: потому что в форме телефон валяется в поле adress (а используется addres), а поля phone нет и в помине.

Comment: Честно говоря не дружу с PHP!

Comment: @Grosso2020, могу утогда порекомендовать нанять программиста.

Comment: Нанимать программиста чтобы решить такую проблемку? проще задать вопрос все таки

Comment: @Grosso2020, как мы видим, проблемка не решается, несмотря на то, что ответ я уже дал.

Comment: Проблема решается телефон появился..в html как то не заглянул. Спасибо!

Comment: @Grosso2020, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.